# Renci.SshNet preaccept key with known fingerprint

Tags: c#, ssh

I have some code that connects to a third party with SFTP using renci.sshnet library. The third party is updating their key on the server and has sent the updated fingerprint. I have searched high and low on the inter webs and can not find how to implement this new fingerprint so our app will continue to connect when the key change happens in a couple of weeks. The app is non interactive and would not allow me to accept the new key when connecting even if that were an option.

Could someone help me find where this fingerprint should be put so that my app will accept the new key automatically?

Comment: will this help? https://www.jokecamp.com/blog/connecting-to-sftp-with-key-file-and-password-using-ssh-net/

Comment: @urlreader i am not using a key file unfortunately. its just a username and password. When the third party migrates to the new key, I am assuming my application will fail to connect as the new fingerprint wont match what we have used in the past. I was told that we need to add this new fingerprint to our server, but all I can find is how to do this on Linux, not windows, which seems to store these somewhere different.

Answer (score 0):

I found a manual way to accept the key fingerprint using PuTTy. After the host key is cached in the registry, our console application (which uses Renci.SshNet) connects with no problem.

After installing PuTTy, you can open a command prompt and type the following:

```
D:\> "c:\Program Files (x86)\SimonTatham\PuTTY\psftp.exe" "userName@hostName"
```

The response from PuTTy will explain that the host key is not cached, it will provide you with the signature, and then ask you that if you trust this host, to enter "y" to add the key.

```
The server's host key is not cached in the registry. You
have no guarantee that the server is the computer you
think it is.
The server's rsa2 key fingerprint is:
ssh-rsa 2048 34:12:3c:2c:a3:90:29:e7:81:f3:96:d6:06:3e:f5:29
If you trust this host, enter "y" to add the key to
PuTTY's cache and carry on connecting.
If you want to carry on connecting just once, without
adding the key to the cache, enter "n".
If you do not trust this host, press Return to abandon the
connection.
Store key in cache? (y/n) _
```

After you enter "y" (without quotes) and press enter, the prompt will ask you for the password. If you have the password you can enter it and start the connection.

You can use the key to connect with PuTTy by adding switch -i AS follows:

```
D:\> "c:\Program Files (x86)\SimonTatham\PuTTY\psftp.exe" "userName@hostName" -i "\\path_to_key\private_key.ppk"
```

The key has to be in PuTTy's format.

I know it is not a straight solution, but it is a work around that, well, works.